# Radio Button not identified

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

I have tried a number of Ruby/Watir options to identify these two radio buttons and I can't do it. I want to `.flash` the radio button first then `.set` one of them.

```
browser.radio(:name => "appchoice_apps", :text => "Supervisor Console").flash
browser.radio(:span => "appchoice_supervisor").flash
```

I am not sure what else to try. I am very new here and I apologize for burning up your time.

```
<span id="appchoice_supervisor" style="visibility: visible;">
  <input type="radio" name="appchoice_apps"></input>
  Supervisor Console
</span>
<span id="appchoice_oa" style="display: block;">
  <input type="radio" checked="" name="appchoice_apps"><input>
  Associate Desktop
  <br></br>
</span>
```

Comment: Probably, you should explain more about what you want to do.

Comment: my apologies for not being specific.  I want to '.flash' first then '.set' in a separate line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1 - By Text**

The first example will not work because the text "Supervisor Console" is a sibling of the radio button rather than a text of the radio button.

```
browser.radio(:name => "appchoice_apps", :text => "Supervisor Console").flash
```

To check the sibling text, you can try getting the span by its text and then navigating to the radio button:

```
browser.span(:text => "Supervisor Console").radio.flash
```

**Solution 2 - By Parent ID**

The second example will not work because `span` is not a valid identifier.

```
browser.radio(:span => "appchoice_supervisor").flash
```

Like the first solution, you can locate the span by its id and then look for a radio button within that span:

```
browser.span(:id => "appchoice_supervisor").radio.flash
```